# retrieve all permissions of a given user for all clients in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

There are APIs in Keycloak to retrieve all permissions of a User for a given client. However, I am looking for an API in keycloak[v17] which gives me all permissions for a given user across all clients in Keycloak.

e.g below API gets all roles associated with that user -
 `https://{{host}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users/69622925-99af-a12765e1f143/role-mappings`

Is there an API which will get me all permissions associated with a user across all clients [or resources]?